# How to change translation files from client

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization, translation, ngx-translate

I'm building a web application with the option to change languages. Now I want to have the option to change some of the translations directly on the client (while someone is logged in with an admin account). This should then change the translation files on the server.

I haven't decided whether to use ngx-translate or angular's i18n yet.